# How to resolve DB.php failed to open stream fatel error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I download code from git then install it on localhost, its showing me that's an error how to resolve it

I have made a database connection I am using Codeigniter framework

```
composer.json file 
{
    "description": "The CodeIgniter framework",
    "name": "codeigniter/framework",
    "type": "project",
    "homepage": "https://codeigniter.com",
    "license": "MIT",
    "support": {
        "forum": "http://forum.codeigniter.com/",
        "wiki": "https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/codeigniter",
        "source": "https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter"
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.7"
    },
    "suggest": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "Provides better randomness in PHP 5.x"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "mikey179/vfsStream": "1.1.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.* || 5.*"
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaZqt.png)

```
database.php database connection file

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'ems_db',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

how to resolve that issue

> Message: require_once(C:\wamp64\www\ems\system\database/DB.php):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>
> ( ! ) Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
> 'C:\wamp64\www\ems\system\database/DB.php'
> (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in
> C:\wamp64\www\ems\system\core\Loader.php on line 381
>
> Message: require_once(): Failed opening required
> 'C:\wamp64\www\ems\system\database/DB.php'
> (include_path='.;C:\php\pear')

I had a composer updated but still showing that issue.